# Math Function Mesh

Tags: mathematics

Could someone help me understand how to enter an X,Y,Z equation in Math Function Add on?

Here is a sample equation:
Cos(x)+Cos(y)+Cos(z) = 0
range -pi to pi

Thank you very much :)
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Some help on how it looks
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/636320-how-to-plot-cos-x-cos-y-cos-z-0

How to use the add-on in Blender
https://youtu.be/JdoFjxu605c

You may also want to try using geometry nodes will allow you to vary parameters in multiple ways.
[Using Geometry Nodes to create and plot equations / functions](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/248789/using-geometry-nodes-to-create-and-plot-equations-functions)

Another way to add the equation using the math nodes add-on. Math Formula addon v1.2.0 https://youtube.com/watch?v=II_0Ep1z-Ks

Also could use Animation Nodes (but takes a bit of learning)
[How to create explicit (parametric) functions in animation node?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/135933/how-to-create-explicit-parametric-functions-in-animation-node)

Also if the equation is complex here's a way to import it into blender https://youtu.be/rd7TTVYnz3c

Comment: Rick, thank you very much for taking the time and answering my question. Of all options, personally,  I prefer math nodes add on. It is worth going through the learning curve and all. Thank you again.

Comment: Your very welcome the members here have helped me tremendously, so when I can help I try to give back as much as possible.